# Highest score in Java

Tags: java

I have a question which asks me to enter some exam score to find the highest and the lowest score overall. (Highlighted question.)
[image: The question]

```
    float sum = 0, score1, score2 = 0, score3 = 0; 

    do
    {
        System.out.println("Enter a score [negative score to quit]: ");

        Scanner Score1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        score1 = Score1.nextFloat();


        if (score1>score2)
            {
                max = score1;
                min = score2;
            }

        else if(score1<score2)
            {
                max = score2;
                min = score1;
            }

        else{
                score3 = score2;                    
            }

        }


    }
    while (score1>=0);

    System.out.printf("Minimun Score = %.0f\n", min);
    System.out.printf("Maximum Score = %.0f\n", max);



    Enter a score [negative score to quit]: 
    99
    Enter a score [negative score to quit]: 
    1
    Enter a score [negative score to quit]: 
    6
    Enter a score [negative score to quit]: 
    5
    Enter a score [negative score to quit]: 
    -1

    Minimum Score = 5
    Maximum Score = 6

    BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 7 seconds)
```

The problem is it only compares the latest 2 score that I entered.
How do i fix this?

Comment: You have 3 variables but the user enters 5 values... Maybe you contemplate about this for a second. Then you do some research regarding arrays. Because that is what you should be using here.

Comment: that is because, you are creating a new scanner object everytime.

Comment: get rid of score2, and always compare your score 1 to min and max

Comment: @mlecz It works, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Logic in `if-else` ladder is incorrect.

You may find following useful:

```
 class Test
 {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        try(Scanner Score1 = new Scanner(System.in))
        {
            //Marks are in range of 0-100
            float curNum, max = -1, min = 101, sum = 0, sumsq = 0; 
            boolean flg = true;

            while(flg)
            {
                System.out.println("Enter a score [negative score to quit]: ");
                curNum = Score1.nextFloat();
                if(curNum<0) break;
                if(max < curNum) max = curNum;
                if(min > curNum) min = curNum;
                sum += curNum;
                sumsq += (curNum*curNum);
            }
            System.out.printf("Minimun Score = %.0f\n", min);
            System.out.printf("Maximum Score = %.0f\n", max);
        }

    }
 }
```

You can find it working [here](https://ideone.com/MIFXf1)

Answer (score 0):

The do-while  logic may not work in the above code.   see the working code below..

```
    float sum = 0, score = 0;
    float min = 0, max = 0, ave = 0;
    Scanner stdInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter the scores: ");
    min = max = score = stdInput.nextFloat();
    do {
        System.out.println("Enter a score [negative score to quit]: ");
        if (score > max) {
            max = score;
        }else if (score < min) {
            min = score;
        }           
        sum += score;
        // Read the input here  so that, the code does not process the negative input.
        score = stdInput.nextFloat();   
    } while (score >= 0);

    System.out.println(min);
    System.out.println(max);
```